# Render multiple values, separated by line break, within a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, textarea, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am rendering a dynamic form in angular. When attribute has multiple values I wish to render them within a textarea. Each value on its own line.

But cant't get it to work!

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_text">
  <label for="{{field.displayName}}">{{field.displayName}}</label>
  <br />  
  <div ng-if="field.multivalue == '0'">
    <input id="{{field.displayName}}" type="text" ng-model="formValues[field.displayName]" placeholder="{{ field.theValues[0]}}" />
  </div>       
  <div ng-if="field.multivalue == '1'">
    <textarea rows="field.numberOfValues"> 
      <p ng-repeat="value in field.theValues track by $index">
      {{value}}&#10;
      </p>
    </textarea> 
  </div>
</script>
```

This is what i get and I think it is because I am rendering the

element with each ng-repeat loop and the textarea does not admit it:

[image]

Can I do an ng-repeat without any html element "paragraph" in this case? 
Or any other way of getting this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
  <div ng-if="field.multivalue == '1'">
    <textarea  rows="{{field.numberOfValues}}" cols="50">
      {{field.theValues.join("&#10;");}}
    </textarea>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addValue(field)">Add value </button>
  </div>
```

The button runs the following function but is only there for testing:

```
  $scope.addValue = function(field) {
    field.theValues[(field.numberOfValues)] = "aaaa";
    field.numberOfValues++;
  };
```

But for some reason I am getting an indention on the first line:

[image]

I fixed the indention problem with the "white-space" attribute:

```
<textarea rows="{{field.numberOfValues}}" cols="50" style="white-space: nowrap;">
```